# X509UsernameRetrieverClassName ignored in tomcat 6 configuration

Tags: java, tomcat

we have configured a JNDIRealm for our tomcat 6.0.32 installation.
Clients gain access to the webapp via Client-Cert authentication. The username
extracted from the certificate is of the form "CN=..., OU=.., O=.., L=.., ST=.."

Since we are only interested in the value of CN we wrote a X509UsernameRetrieverClass, placed the jar in $TOMCAT_HOME/lib and 
configured it in the JNDIRealm:

```
    <Context docBase="MYApp.war" path="/myapp" reloadable="true">
    <Realm 
        X509UsernameRetrieverClassName="com.my.custom.X509UsernameRetriever" 
        authentication="simple" 
        className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm" 
        connectionName="ldapuser" 
        connectionPassword="****" 
        connectionURL="ldap://localhost:389" 
        roleBase="xxxx" 
        roleName="cn" 
        roleSearch="(member={0})" 
        roleSubtree="true" 
        userBase="xxxx" 
        userSearch="(cn={0})" 
        userSubtree="true"/>
    </Context>
```

However, when tomcat boots up we get the following warning:

```
    WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context/Realm} Setting property 'X509UsernameRetrieverClassName' to 'com.my.custom.X509UsernameRetriever' did not find a matching property.
```

The configuration is ignored and users aren't authenticated, presumably because the defaut retriever is used returning the long winded username which isn't found
in the underlying ldap system...

The same configuration works fine for tomcat 7. I can't really see what we did wrong. The X509UsernameRetrieverClassName is documented. https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/realm.html#JNDI_Directory_Realm_-_org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm
does anyone have any ideas ?

thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved the problem.
the X509UsernameRetriever class doesn't appear in tomcat 6 until version 6.0.36. hence the attribute being ignored in version 6.0.32

The workaround was to override the JNDIRealm.getPrincipal(X509Certificate usercert) in a custom class.